# MySQL query from python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Attempting to draw some data from a MySQL database in python however I've run into a roadblock. If one collumn 1 had names of people and collumn 2 had their ages, how could I in python query only those that were over 50 for example. So far I have this however it's not working and oddly isn't throwing up any errors. It's probably just a rookie mistake, I did look at some other threads but they dealt with different problems and/or did it another way.

```
def name_function(number): 
 ## [connection code]    
sql = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE age >= "+number+" ORDER BY name"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, lose the extra quotes around `number`.

Also, you are much better off using query parameters.

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM names WHERE age >= %s ORDER BY name'
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql, [number])
```